# How to resolve unserialize issue

Tags: magento-2.1, fatal-error, setup-di-compile, magento2.2

My extension has stopped working since updating to Magento 2.2.0

When running di:compile we get the following error:

```
Errors during compilation:
    Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionUpdater\Option
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\collection. Actual type: \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\Collection; File:
/public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/CollectionUpdater/Option.php

    Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionUpdater\Value
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\collection. Actual type: \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\Collection; File:
/public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/CollectionUpdater/Value.php

Total Errors Count: 2

  [Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]
  Error during compilation
```

When checking exceptions.php we get the following error:

> main.CRITICAL: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 169 bytes in /public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/StockProvider.php on line 181 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 169 bytes in /public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/StockProvider.php on line 181 at /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}

No product can be added to the cart and the plugin isn't loading correctly on the product admin pages.

Comment: This module currently is not compatible with the Magento 2.2. If you have any questions - address them to the [MageWorx support team](https://www.mageworx.com/support) (they provide a free lifetime support)

Comment: I had, it was just taking too long to get it sorted so I branched out. Ended up rolling back to 2.1.9 while they make it compatible with 2.2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per magento 2.2 release note, Now you can not use direct **serialize** and **unserialize** PHP functions.

To solve this issue Inject `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` class for serialize and unserialize values.

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serialize,
    ...
) {
    $this->serialize = $serialize;
}
```

Now use `$this->serialize`

```
 $this->serialize->unserialize($serializeVal); //To Unserialize Value
 $this->serialize->serialize($unserializeVal); //To Serialize Value
```

**As per Magento 2.2 Release Note**

> Security enhancements
>
> In general, we’ve removed serialize/unserialize from most the code to improve protection against remote code execution attacks. We’ve enhanced protection of code where use of object serialization or unserialization was unavoidable. Additionally, we’ve increased our use of output escaping to protect against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: That's great thanks, Prince. I didn't catch that in the release.

Comment: Great explanation for both version. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1 Delete all the folders from pub/static

2. Delete folders like cache, view_preprocessed, page_cache and generation from var folder.
3. After that run command:  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Then error will be fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me creating magento_umask file in the root directory with the appropriate umask for the server.

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html for additional details.